# Are there any Stack Overflow rules regarding line indentation in formatted code?

Tags: discussion, edits, code-formatting

... or in other words: Why would someone want to edit an answer just to remove four leading spaces of a few code lines?
Example: https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/73159227/5 - should I have known better or is it just a matter of taste?

Comment: When you use a text/code editor do you indent your entire codebase by 4 spaces? Probably not, because it's unnecessary and unsightly, so why would you do it on Stack Overflow?

Comment: The editor probably assumed that the extra indentation was a mistake due to unfamiliarity with markdown

Comment: I don't understand why there is a question. Does it *bother you* that this edit was made? Why?

Comment: @NickstandswithUkraine, that's a rhetorical question isn't it. If there is more Text than Code, indentation can make sense IMO, especially when it's an old programming language not being commonly known

Comment: @KarlKnechtel, I wonder if I'm the only one who wonders. So if "everyone" like a majority agrees those four leading space are somewhat displaced in that answer, I'd probably change my perspective

Comment: Please point out the rule that we have to keep the four leading spaces.

Comment: The extra indentation does feel out of place. Usually indentation in code is used to demarcate blocks (functions, classes, etc.), having indented code out of nowhere makes one feel that there is some missing context.

Comment: In this case... i think it's fine. If it were a case of someone converting 4 spaces tabs to 2, or vice versa, that's not a useful edit. Removing an indention across the entire code sample that doesn't serve *any* purpose is a good edit, it allows more content to display on that line before horizontal scrolling for users on mobile.

Comment: i usually rollback, it is my choice what format i choose

Comment: @nbk Is it really a format choice to indent all of your code by 4 spaces? What possible purpose would that serve?

Comment: @JohnMontgomery some people need it tidy so they take offence and remove them other like i if there is nothing else what needs fixing let it be, like i said rollback if you don't like the changes

Comment: @nbk It’s not a good idea to encourage people to rollback good edits; that sort of thing leads to suspensions when done repeatedly.

Comment: @BSMP a good edit, is **not** to remove 4 spaces, and if you don't like the edit made it is better tpo roll back as to ask on meta or get angry about, there  are only rarely good edit

Comment: @StefanWuebbe, I see that edit was totally pointless. To me the person doing that didn't even know VFP and was just trying to be smart doing some unnecessary editing work in someone else's code. SO is a strange place you would even be downvoted asking it.

Comment: @StefanWuebbe, let it go. You can even see the disrespect done here by a lot of downvotes. Let it be like SO moderators like.

Comment: @CetinBasoz, my friend, no problem, to me it appears as human communication can be a complex thing, but always interesting and I don't feel offended :-)

Comment: Not in the example, but sometimes for avoiding the need to use horizontal scrolling (for readability).

Answer (score 14):

It's important to [look at things in perspective](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/73159227/4)...

[image]

...and to be *fair*, the new edit makes the post a bit more readable and would be something we'd trust someone with expanded edit privileges to do.

It *is* a matter of taste and it wouldn't be a good edit if there were *other* issues, but I'm really not seeing a problem here.

Comment: What makes you think it makes it more readable? I see a big problem, first it doesn't provide any sort of `more readability`, second that doesn't add a single thing to the post content, but sounds like a disrespect to the poster. If it were my post, seeing that edit I would feel offended and roll it back.

Comment: @CetinBasoz:  White space without any real structure or purpose screams incredibly loudly to me.  Because this content is licensed CC-by-SA, *so long* as the edit made to the post is not actively detrimental to the overall post or the site itself, you have no real basis to "take offense" and roll it back.  Should you pursue that approach you would run head-first into a diamond moderator telling you to knock those kinds of rollback wars off.

Comment: As you said it seems loud "to you". You like using fancy buzzwords that I don't understand. What I see is some moderators like doing offending work.

Comment: @CetinBasoz you, as the author of your post, can always choose to rollback if you are such offended. More often than not you'd get your way. The only time you wouldn't, would be when you're actively rolling back a *good* edit, thus vandalizing your post. something minor like the example here wouldn't likely come to that.

Comment: @CetinBasoz:  I don't know how else to explain to you that you can't own offense on content that is community edited and modifiable. Yes, it's your answer, but others can and are capable of coming in to modify it for minor readability purposes, such as what was done in this very case.  Saying "that's offensive" and resisting that change would land you in hot water sooner than the person who made the "offensive" edit.